# Offlineimap mail count does not match Gmail's

Tags: email, synchronization

I'm syncing my gmail account ('All Mail' and 'Sent' folder) with offlineimap to my harddrive. But it appears to me some emails are not downloaded. I disabled the conversation view in gmail and it shows me 4728 mails in 'All Mail'. Offlineimap creates 4703 files, shouldn't these two numbers match?

~/.offlineimaprc

```
[Repository gmail-Local]
type = Maildir
localfolders = ~/mail/gmail

[Repository gmail-Remote]
type = Gmail
remoteuser = me@gmail.com
remotepass = passw
readonly = True
createfolders = False
ssl = yes
sslcacertfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

nametrans = lambda folder: re.sub(' ', '_', folder)
folderfilter = lambda foldername: foldername in ['[Gmail]/All Mail', '[Google Mail]/All Mail', '[Google Mail]/Sent Mail', '[Gmail]/Sent Mail']
```

When I do:

```
~/mail/gmail/[Google_Mail].All_Mail]$ find . -type f | wc -l
4703

offlineimap --version
6.5.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On closer look those missing 25 mails most likely are chat conversations which show up in Gmail within 'All Mail'.

To sync them, you need to ensure the Chats label is visible in IMAP:

Click the Gear icon > Settings > Labels > Check the checkbox "Show in IMAP" for chats.